# igraph graph.lattice for all combinations (in R)

Tags: r, igraph

Greetings:  This graph seems like something that should be pretty straightforward using the igraph package for R.  I am trying to figure out which arguments I need to pass to obtain the edges between sub-patterns and super-patterns.  In this example, a item set of 5 items is represented.

[image: item.lattice.plot]

I am sure this is solved with the `graph.lattice` function in `igraph` but I haven't figured out the arguments to pass.  Please note that the graph presented comes from *Data Mining: Concepts and Techniques* (Han, Kamber, & Pei, 2011).

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `graph.lattice` is capable of creating this kind of graph. But you can define a new function:

```
graph.comb <- function(word) {
  # creates graph objects from character combination in word
  # example graph.comb("abc")

  do_layer <- function(words) {
    do.call( rbind, lapply(words, function(word){
      l_vec <- sapply(seq_len(nchar(word)), function(l) substring(word, l, l))
      w_comb <- apply(combn(l_vec, nchar(word)-1), 2, paste, collapse = "")
      w_df <- expand.grid(from = w_comb, to = word, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }))
  }

  df_edges <- data.frame(from = word, to = NA, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df2 <- df_edges
  while( min(nchar(df_edges$from)) > 0) {
    df2 <- do_layer(df2$from)
    df_edges <- rbind(df_edges, df2)
  }
  df_edges <- df_edges[complete.cases(df_edges), ]
  df_edges <- df_edges[!duplicated(df_edges), ]
  return(graph.data.frame(df_edges ))
}
```

Use it with any character string:

```
g1 <- graph.comb("abcd")
plot(g1, layout = layout.sugiyama(g1)$layout )
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @ bergant: great answer! can you please take a look at my question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71191060/r-making-trees-from-lists thank you!