# R: Making Trees from Lists

Tags: r, list, tree, data-visualization, combinations

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following data frame that contains different food and drink choices:

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame = data.frame(food = c("pizza", "tacos", "nachos"),
 drinks = c("water", "coffee", "pop"))
```

I then made a "list" that contains every possible selection of these food and drink items:

```
lst1 <- lapply(data_frame, function(x) c("none", unlist(lapply(seq_len(length(x)), function(i) combn(x, i, FUN = paste, collapse = " & ")))))
```

**My Question:** I would like to take this above list and make a "tree" that shows every possible combination of food and drink choices that can be ordered together - this should look something like this

[image]

**Is it possible to do this in R using libraries such as "data.tree" and "ggplot2"?**

For example, here is a (incomplete) sample of the kind of tree I am looking for, when there are 2 variables with 2 "types" of factors (first variable: 1,2 ; second variable: A, B):

[image]

I found this previous stackoverflow post ([igraph graph.lattice for all combinations (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774012/igraph-graph-lattice-for-all-combinations-in-r)) - but I am not sure how to adapt the code provided there for my problem.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: How about [`lobstr::tree`](https://lobstr.r-lib.org/reference/tree.html) and `Hmisc::tree`? I reckon those functions are close to your desired outcome. I'm not sure if you are getting the desired combinations view...

Comment: @ Konrad: thank you for your reply! I will check it out!

Answer (score 2):

## Update

```
v <- unlist(df)
l <- lapply(
  seq_along(v),
  function(k) {
    combn(v, k, paste0, collapse = "&")
  }
)
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(seq(length(l) - 1), function(k) {
    expand.grid(l[c(k, k + 1)])
  })
) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() %>%
  plot(layout = layout_with_sugiyama(.)$layout)**
```

which generates a tree plot like below

[image]

**Dummy Data**
For simplicity, we used the following smaller dummy data

```
df <- data.frame(food = c("a", "b"), drink = 1:2)
```

---

## Previous Answer

What about `expand.grid` over `lst1` to create all combinations?

```
> expand.grid(lst1)
                     food               drinks
1                    none                 none
2                   pizza                 none
3                   tacos                 none
4                  nachos                 none
5           pizza & tacos                 none
6          pizza & nachos                 none
7          tacos & nachos                 none
8  pizza & tacos & nachos                 none
9                    none                water
10                  pizza                water
11                  tacos                water
12                 nachos                water
13          pizza & tacos                water
14         pizza & nachos                water
15         tacos & nachos                water
16 pizza & tacos & nachos                water
17                   none               coffee
18                  pizza               coffee
19                  tacos               coffee
20                 nachos               coffee
21          pizza & tacos               coffee
22         pizza & nachos               coffee
23         tacos & nachos               coffee
24 pizza & tacos & nachos               coffee
25                   none                  pop
26                  pizza                  pop
27                  tacos                  pop
28                 nachos                  pop
29          pizza & tacos                  pop
30         pizza & nachos                  pop
31         tacos & nachos                  pop
32 pizza & tacos & nachos                  pop
33                   none       water & coffee
34                  pizza       water & coffee
35                  tacos       water & coffee
36                 nachos       water & coffee
37          pizza & tacos       water & coffee
38         pizza & nachos       water & coffee
39         tacos & nachos       water & coffee
40 pizza & tacos & nachos       water & coffee
41                   none          water & pop
42                  pizza          water & pop
43                  tacos          water & pop
44                 nachos          water & pop
45          pizza & tacos          water & pop
46         pizza & nachos          water & pop
47         tacos & nachos          water & pop
48 pizza & tacos & nachos          water & pop
49                   none         coffee & pop
50                  pizza         coffee & pop
51                  tacos         coffee & pop
52                 nachos         coffee & pop
53          pizza & tacos         coffee & pop
54         pizza & nachos         coffee & pop
55         tacos & nachos         coffee & pop
56 pizza & tacos & nachos         coffee & pop
57                   none water & coffee & pop
58                  pizza water & coffee & pop
59                  tacos water & coffee & pop
60                 nachos water & coffee & pop
61          pizza & tacos water & coffee & pop
62         pizza & nachos water & coffee & pop
63         tacos & nachos water & coffee & pop
64 pizza & tacos & nachos water & coffee & pop
```

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding: thank you for your answer! Do you know can we plot this tree? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob You are welcome! Could you show an exmaple of expected output in a tree graph according to your data example in your question (manually draw a graph and put in out post, for example)? I guess there might be some `igraph` solutions but depending on which kind of tree plot you want.

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding: thank you for your reply! I think something that looks like this, that shows how the combinations branch out

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnnJ6.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhOFQ.png

Comment: @stats_noob Okay, I will take a look later of today.

Comment: @stats_noob not sure if you are interested in interactive plots but you might want to check library([collapsibleTree](https://github.com/AdeelK93/collapsibleTree)).

Comment: @ismirsehregal Seems a promising and interesting proposal :)

Comment: @stats_noob I updated my answer so you can see if that is what you want

Comment: @  ismirsehregal : thank you for your this link - it looks very interesting! If you have time, could you please show me how to use it?

Comment: @  ThomasIsCoding: Thank you so much for your answer! I know I have asked a lot from you already - if you have time later in the week, could you please see if it is possible to make something like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhOFQ.png) - I am going to try and see if we can use the link that (https://github.com/AdeelK93/collapsibleTree) @ismirsehregal  provided to change the format of this tree so that it looks more like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhOFQ.png . If this is not possible, I will stick with the AMAZING work that you have already done. Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob Could you explain a bit how the formt is interpreted? I am a bit confused by its meaning.

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding: Thank you for your reply! The picture I drew (in MS Paint) is inspired by this post on Math Stackoverflow: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4386519/counting-combinations-of-hats-and-scarves-experiments-with-the-power-set-2n

Comment: Imagine you have two variables : First Variable (1,2) and Second Variable (A, B).  This means that there are 16 different ways (2^x, 2^4 = 16) you can pick combinations from the first variable and second variable. For example, you can pick everything (1,2,A,B), you can pick nothing (0,0), you can pick (1,2,A), etc

Comment: I tried your answer with the following data : df <- data.frame(food = c("a", "b", "c", "c"), drink = 1:4)

Comment: I got the following graph : https://imgur.com/a/f9lgnHe ... I wonder if for larger data sets, some visualization techniques might exist to better show combinations that might exist (even if some combinations are omitted from the visualization to make things clear) ?

Comment: @stats_noob It seem not easy to make better visualization since you have massive edges the graph.